# Fabric 2: configuring sudo passwords for various hosts

Tags: python, ssh, python-fabric-2

I am looking for a way to configure passwords for "sudoing" in the various hosts targeted by a `fabfile.py`. I accept "clear" passwords" in a `~/.fabric.py|yaml|json` but **not** in the `fabfile.py`.

Unless I didn't read correctly, the fabric documentation shows how to provide a common sudo password in a configuration file, but I have different users (managed through `~/.ssh/config`) and different passwords for those hosts. And the system admin do not accept to let sudoing without password.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345184/fabric-difference-sudo-runsudo-cmd

Answer (score 0):

current workaround would be.
managing as per [this](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1983).
where you can provide ssh_password as a argument.

I think you are accepting and storing clear text password.

```
fabric_connection.sudo("ls -al /root", password=sudo_password)
```

manage your passwords differently to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks, I knew this one, but I need the glue to have these passwords passed in through a configuration file. This does not answer I expected, sorry.